# For loop only runs once to delete emails

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, for-loop, automation

I'm attempting a for loop using java/selenium to run numerous times to delete emails, but it only runs once.  I'm still a beginner at this and can not figure out what it is that I'm doing wrong.  Can someone please provide me with some assistance?  Your help is greatly appreciated. Below is the code that I'm running:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class deleteYahooEmail {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/lena/WebDrivers/geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); //launches the browser


        driver.get("https://login.yahoo.com/");
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            driver.findElement(By.id("login-username")).sendKeys("someemailhere@yahoo.com");

            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.id("login-signin")).click(); 

            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.id("login-passwd")).sendKeys("passwrdhere");

            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.id("login-signin")).click();

            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.id("header-mail-button")).click();

            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

 for (int i = 0; i >10; i = i + 1) {

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@type='button'                            and @data-test-id='checkbox']"))).click();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='button' and @data-test-id='toolbar-delete']")).click();

                }



        }


    }
```

Comment: Your for loop is in-correct. A for loop consists of 3 components, The first is initialization `int i = 0;` 2. Condition `i < 10;` basically saying while i is less than 10, carry on executing the body of the for loop. 3. Increment/decrement this is carried after every iteration of the loop, `i ++` eventually your `i ` will = 10 and your loop will no longer execute. So your loop should look as follow: `for(int i = 0; i  < 10; i ++) { do something } `

Comment: I changed this to suggested method and nothing happens.  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@type='button' and @data-test-id='checkbox']"))).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='button' and @data-test-id='toolbar-delete']")).click();

 }

Comment: Have you tried the de-bugger? I'm not familiar with your code so unfortunately I can't take this any further. Good luck!

Comment: I'm new at this, and need to learn the debugger. I did provide the complete code, you just need to add your own username and password.  But thank you for trying though!

Comment: I've also, tried using a for - while loop, but the code only runs through only once and not a continuous loop, as well:  int x = 1; 

 while (x <= 4) 
           {
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@type='button' and @data-test-id='checkbox']"))).click();
    
    
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='button' and @data-test-id='toolbar-delete']")).click();
    
x++; 
           }

Comment: @Bradley my initial code read as: for ( i =0; i >10; i = i +1) { with something to execute}. I believe that both my initial version and what you recommended would have provided the same outcome of incrementing “i by 1”. Is this correct? But in any case, I’m still having issues with the for loop not running continuously. But, thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

`i ++` and `i = i + 1` are the same.

The issue with your for-loop is that your condition statement is always `false` as a result the loop will never execute.

Your basically saying, whilst i is more than 10 execute the for-loop body, can you see why this will never execute? It will never run as your are initialising i with the value of 0. See my diagram.

For more info on loops see: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_for_loop.asp

[image]

Comment: Yes, I understand.  Thank you for clarifying.  (Back to the drawing board.  I will figure this out.)  Thanks again!